# AMD installer user agreement prompt

Tags: windows-10

I've successfully installed `AMD drivers` but still getting a user `license agreement prompt` (as shown on the screenshot) every system reboot. Why does the installer keep asking that hence I've finished the installation and doesn't run the installer any more?[image]

My it be that i should install all the drivers from the (disabled by default) `Administrator` account because I'm doing it from the default main user account (created during win install)?

Comment: Well, did you click the Accept button or not? Getting a license accept dialog with every boot is not what I'd call a successful install. The built-in Administrator account is not needed for anything, except a few rare corruption scenarios.

Comment: If nothing else you can always use Display Driver Uninstaller. It will tell you to reboot at each step. This solves most problems. https://www.guru3d.com/files_details/display_driver_uninstaller_download.html